# Smallest sum of pairs

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, math

Given **2N-points** in a **2D-plane**, you have to group them into **N pairs** such that the overall sum of distances between the points of all of the pairs is the minimum possible value.**The desired output is only the sum.**

In other words, if **a1,a2,..an** are the  distances between points of first, second...and nth pair respectively, then **(a1+a2+...an) should be minimum.**

Let us consider this test-case, if the **2*5** points are : 
**{20,20},
{40, 20},
{10, 10},
{2, 2},
{240, 6},
{12, 12},
{100, 120},
{6, 48},
{12, 18},
{0, 0}**

The desired output is **237**.

This is not my homework,I am inquisitive about different approaches rather than brute-force.

Comment: This is known as the traveling salesman problem.

Comment: No, that is different from TSP. But looking at TSP may a good point to start from.

Comment: @Doc Brown: Please enlighten me :)

Comment: @Jason. Not TSP at all. It is a Matching problem. Which is in P :-)

Comment: I have removed the code-golf tag.

Comment: @Jason Punyon: This is quite different from TSP. TSP is about finding a distance-minimizing path that visits every vertex exactly once. This problem is about pairing off the points in a way that minimizes the sum of the distances in each pair. For example, consider a rectangle that is very wide relative to its height. Then you should pair off vertices that are endpoints of the short vertical segments to minimize the sum of the distances between the pairs. In TSP, you output a path that travels the two vertical segments once each and one of the wide horizontal segments once.

Comment: @Jason: in TSP, you have N points p1, p2, p2,.. And you have to find a permutation of them so that the sum of the N distances of consecutive points gets minimal (distance N is the distance from the last point to the first). The OP was talking of 2N points, so I thoht he means grouping them into N pair (giving a sum of N distances, TSP would give 2N distances).

Comment: @pieguy. Please don't tag it wrong just to get more people to see it. I will leave it, but I expect you will tag it correctly soon.

Comment: @ Moron : How does tagging code-golf is wrong ? Please enlighten me :)

Comment: code-golf is a contest that focuses on finding the shortest length code that will solve a problem, sacrificing legibility, maintainibility, efficiency, flexibility, good practices, and robustness to achieve the goal. That is not what you are asking for here.

Comment: When you say, "distances between the points of the pairs", do you mean the midpoint between the points which make the pair?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be looking for [Minimum weight perfect matching](http://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~wcook/papers/IJOCmat.pdf).

There are algorithms to exploit the fact that these are points in a plane. This paper: [Mincost Perfect Matching in the Plane](http://www.cs.uiowa.edu/~kvaradar/paps/daq.pdf) has an algorithm and also mentions some previous work on it.

---

As requested, here is a brief description of a "simple" algorithm for minimum weighted perfect matching in a graph. This is a short summary of parts of the chapter on weighted matching in the book *Combinatorial Optimization, Algorithms and Complexity* by Papadimitriou & Steiglitz.

Say you are given a weighted undirected graph G(with an even number of nodes). The graph can be considered a complete weighted graph, by adding the missing edges and assigning them very large weights.

Suppose the vertices are labelled 1 to n and the weight of edge between vertices i and j is c(i,j).

We have n(n-1)/2 variables x(i,j) which denote a matching of G. x(i,j) = 1 if the edge between i and j is in the matching and x(i,j) = 0 if it isn't.

Now the matching problem can be written as the Linear Programming Problem:

**minimize Sum c(i,j) * x(i,j)**

subject to the condition that

***Sum x(1,j) = 1***, where j ranges from 1 to n.

***Sum x(2,j) = 1***, where j ranges from 1 to n.
.
.
.

***Sum x(n,j) = 1***, where j ranges from 1 to n.

(Sum x(1,j) = 1 basically means that we are selecting exactly one edge incident the vertex labelled 1.)

And the final condition that

***x(i,j) >= 0***

(we could have said x(i,j) = 0 or 1, but that would not make this a Linear Programming Problem as the constraints are either linear equations or inequalities)

There is a method called the Simplex method which can solve this Linear Programming problem to give an optimal solution in polynomial time in the number of variables.

Now, if G were bipartite, it can be shown that we can obtain an optimal solution such that x(i,j) = 0 or 1. Thus by solving this linear programming problem for a bipartite graph, we get a set of assignments to each x(i,j), each being 0 or 1. We can now get a matching by picking those edges (i,j) for which x(i,j) = 1. The constraints guarantee that it will be a matching with smallest weight.

Unfortunately, this is not true for general graphs (i.e x(i,j) being 0 or 1). Edmonds figured out that this was because of the presence of odd cycles in the graph.

So in addition to the above contraints, Edmonds added the additional constraint that in any subset of vertices of size 2k+1 (i.e of odd size), the number of matched edges is no more than k

Enumerate each odd subset of vertices to get a list of sets S(1), S(2), ..., S(2^n - n). Let size of S(r) be 2*s(r) + 1.

Then the above constraints are, for each set S(r)

***Sum x(i,j) + y(r) = s(r)***, for i, j in S(r).

Edmonds then proved that this was enough to guarantee that each x(i,j) is 0 or 1, thus giving us a minimum weight perfect matching.

Unfortunately, now the number of variables has become exponential in size. So the simplex algorithm, if just run on this as it is, will lead to an exponential time algorithm.

To get past this, Edmonds considers the dual of this linear programming problem (I won't go into details here), and shows that primal-dual algorithm when run on the dual takes only O(n^4) steps to reach a solution, thus giving us a polynomial time algorithm! He shows this by showing that at most O(n) of the y(r) are non-zero at any step of the algorithm (which he calls blossoms).

Here is a link which should explain it in a little more detail: http://www.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/V.Kolmogorov/papers/blossom5.pdf , Section 2.

The book I mentioned before is worth reading (though it can be a bit dry) to get a deeper understanding.

Phew. Hope that helps!

---

Comment: Maybe not quite ... the task here is geometric, not graph-based. You have more freedom without that restriction that all things must be packed into a graph.

Comment: Could you please explain with some test-cases ?

Comment: Me? Well, 2N points in 2d plane is the same as having a complete 2N graph, and that is going to eat up a lot of memory!

Comment: @ Hamish Grubijan : No,my question was for Moron.Thanks :)

Comment: @Moron: that article is hard stuff. The OP is looking for a solution for the special case where G is a complete planar graph. Do you know of any simpler algorithms for this special case?

Comment: Perhaps the so called duality approach can help identify closest pairs sooner. Note that this is computational geometry stuff, not pure algorithms.

Comment: @Moron why not? Not sure what which part you refer to, but basically an entire field of computational geometry emerged precisely because there are some things that you can do better when you do not restrict yourself to a graph data structure. There is still a very intimate relationship, but graph-only approaches (where every point is a vertex and every line segment is an edge) sometimes aren't as good.

Comment: @Doc. Not off the top of my head. I would presume the triangle inequality restriction would be more important than planarity (which it is not, btw). I will update this later when I find something.

Comment: @Doc: I have edited my post to add a link to a (hopefully) faster algorithm. That paper does not seem to have enough details, though.

Comment: @moron Very interesting, but could you please outline the presented algorithm? -- that link seems more of an abstract than an answer to the question. Otherwise I'd no longer wonder why jet physics people use greedy algorithms (maybe with kernels) if CS can only be done in such opaque lingo.

Comment: @honk: Perfect Matching in graphs is a well known problem, you should find plenty of literature on that. As to the link(second one) I gave, I would have to read it myself and try to summarize it. It might be hard to do that though, given the prerequisites needed for even understanding that paper. I might make an attempt, but please don't count on it to happen soon.

Comment: @Moron: I am not much familiar to Minimum weight perfect matching, what I found from goggling doesn't give basic knowledge to implement for my problem.Could you help me in this regard ?

Comment: @Moron: when I wrote 'simpler', I meant 'simpler to understand', not 'faster' :-)

Comment: @Moron: wow, that summary is excellent and IMHO much better to understand than the publication.

Answer (score 1):

Your final sum will mostly be dominated by the largest addend. The simplest algorithm to exploit this could go like this (I cannot prove this):

1. sort points descending by their nearest-neighbor distance
2. form pair of first entry and its nearest neighbor
3. remove pair from list
4. if list not empty goto 1.

This should work very often.

Since you are essentially looking for a clustering algorithm for clusters of 2 [this link](http://arxiv.org/abs/0706.2569) or a search for [clustering algorithms for jet reconstruction](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=+hadron+clustering+algorithm+shower) might be interesting. People in the experimental particle physics community are working on heuristic algorithms for problems like this.

Comment: -1. As I wrote to Hamish, a greedy algo like yours underestimates the difficulty of the problem. And having a short look to your links, they seem to point in a completely wrong direction.

Comment: @Doc I didn't say this would always work, and btw Harmish's algorithm started with the closest pair. Maybe you have something in mind that always works (I would be interested)

Comment: @honk: I think (besides the obvious 'brute force' solution) the links given by Moron contain valid algorithms. They are just hard to read for non-mathematicians and probably not easily to implement.

Comment: @Doc Agree. You or moron should really write up a schematic implementation of the algorithm for this 'simple' case though so we all can understand it. Looking at google results you could easily become the Number 1 hit for this topic ;)

Comment: How do you "sort points by their nearest neighbour distance"? The pairwise nearest neighbour distance doesn't provide a total order for points.

Comment: @nick Agreed, for gridded points this might get it totally wrong. If the points are not on a grid though the difference between half and total order shouldn't matter too much *I'd guess*.

I assume that there is a "loner point" dominating the sum (which has not to hold at all). If the points are too evenly distributed the sum I outlined might easily be dominated not by the first addend, but by the *last*.

But for a not too small number of not too evenly distributed points this should still give a not too bad guess.

Should I remove answer this answer since it depends on too many *not too's*?

Comment: No, my point is that you simply can't sort a list by a property that pairs of elements have unless that property provides a total order - and the euclidian distance between elements isn't that. Perhaps you meant something else by "sort points descending by their nearest-neighbor distance"?

Comment: @nick sure you can: for every point find it's NN, measure the distance, that's the number *this* point gets, sort

Comment: Possibly a simplest case where this algo fails is a set of four points in a line at coords 0, 2, 3 and 5. First the pair (2,3) is chosen as the closest pair, and then only (0,5) remains. Result: 6=(5-0)+(3-2). The correct answer,  though, is 4=(2-0)+(5-3).

Answer (score 0):

After googling a while, I found some other references to **minimum weight perfect matching** algorithms which might be easier to understand (at least, easier to a certain degree).

EDIT

[Here I found a python implementation](http://healthyalgorithms.wordpress.com/2009/03/23/aco-in-python-minimum-weight-perfect-matchings-aka-matching-algorithms-and-reproductive-health-part-4/) of one of those algorithms. It has 837 lines of code (+ some additional unit tests), and I did not try it out by myself. But perhaps you can use it for your case.

[Here is a link](http://www.dcg.ethz.ch/publications/ctw04.pdf) to an approximation algorithm for the problem. Of course, the style of the paper is mathematical, too, but IMHO much easier to understand than the paper of Cook and Rohe. And it states in its preface that it aims exactly for the purpose to be easier to implement than Edmond's original algorithm, since you don't need a linear programming solver.

EDIT2:

After thinking a while about the problem, IMHO it must be possible to set up an [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) search for solving this problem. The search space here is the set of 'partially matchings' (or partially paired point sets). As Moron already wrote in his comments, one can restrict the search to the situation where no pairs with crossing connecting lines exist. The path-cost function (to use the terms from Wikipedia) is the sum of the distances of the already paired points. The heuristic function `h(x)` can be any under-estimation for the remaining distances, for example, when you have `2M` points not paired so far, take the sum of the `M` minimal distances between all of those remaining points.

That one will probably be not as efficient as the algorithm Moron pointed to, but I suspect it will be much better than 'brute force', and much easier to implement.

Comment: The first link you gave has approximation algorithms.

Comment: Ups, you are right, I overlooked that at the first glance. I will edit my answer appropriately.